# Using dplyr to mutate factor variable conditional on numeric variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data from a sports team tracking wins/losses versus other teams with the following structure:

```
Game TotalWins TotalLosses Team1Win Team1Loss Team2Win Team2Loss ...
1    1         0           1        NA        NA       NA
2    1         1           NA       NA        NA       1
3    2         1           NA       NA        1        NA
4    2         2           NA       1         NA       NA
5    3         2           NA       NA        1        NA
...
```

I want to create a factor variable that includes the team the game was played against so that the data looks like this:

```
Game TotalWins TotalLosses Team1Win Team1Loss Team2Win Team2Loss Team
1    1         0           1        NA        NA       NA        Team1
2    1         1           NA       NA        NA       1         Team2
3    2         1           NA       NA        1        NA        Team2
4    2         2           NA       1         NA       NA        Team1
5    3         2           NA       NA        1        NA        Team2
...
```

My thinking (NOT workable code) is essentially this:

```
if (Team1Win == 1 | Team1Loss == 1), Team = "Team1"
if (Team2Win == 1 | Team2Loss == 1), Team = "Team2"
```

I'm really struggling with how to do this in dplyr using mutate. I've tried various approaches with ifelse, recode, etc., but I either keep getting errors or results that are not what I want.

What is correct and most efficient way to make this work in dplyr?

Comment: `mutate(Team = ifelse(is.na(Team1Win) & is.na(Team1Loss), "Team2", "Team1"))`

Comment: Adding to @Vlo's nice comment: the [`ifelse`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) function is a great one for this type of use-case

Comment: @Vlo, that's one of the things I tried before posting (only I tried it with nonmissing values because there are a lot of teams that are all missing, not just two like in my example), and it throws this error:  "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  argument "yes" is missing, with no default"  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @AshLevitt: Yeah, horrible error message for what is probably a syntax issue due to chaining `ifelse`.  Note that the second `ifelse` is the next test if the previous `ifelse` is FALSE.

`df <- df %>%
  mutate(Condition = ifelse(Condition == 'thing1', 'other-thing1',
          ifelse(Condition == 'thing2', 'other-thing2', 'default-thing')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along similar lines to other answers, but with some useful changes:

- `na.rm = TRUE` in `gather`
- `sub` works just fine, no need for `stringr`
- includes the *full* data as per the goal, using a `full_join`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = read.delim(text = 
"Game TotalWins TotalLosses Team1Win Team1Loss Team2Win Team2Loss
1 1 0 1 NA NA NA
2 1 1 NA NA NA 1
3 2 1 NA NA 1 NA
4 2 2 NA 1 NA NA
5 3 2 NA NA 1 NA", sep = " ")

df %>% 
  select(-starts_with("Total")) %>% 
  gather(Team, one, -Game, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-one) %>% 
  mutate(Team = sub("Win|Loss", "", Team)) %>% 
  full_join(df, .)

#> Joining, by = "Game"
#>   Game TotalWins TotalLosses Team1Win Team1Loss Team2Win Team2Loss  Team
#> 1    1         1           0        1        NA       NA        NA Team1
#> 2    2         1           1       NA        NA       NA         1 Team2
#> 3    3         2           1       NA        NA        1        NA Team2
#> 4    4         2           2       NA         1       NA        NA Team1
#> 5    5         3           2       NA        NA        1        NA Team2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a sucker for `dplyr` approaches to things at the moment so I offer a solution using `dplyr` that extends to however many teams you might have. It does also use `tidyr` and `stringr` as helpfully pointed out in the comment by apom below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df = read_delim(
"Game TotalWins TotalLosses Team1Win Team1Loss Team2Win Team2Loss
1 1 0 1 NA NA NA
2 1 1 NA NA NA 1
3 2 1 NA NA 1 NA
4 2 2 NA 1 NA NA
5 3 2 NA NA 1 NA",delim = " ")

df %>% 
  gather("Team",value,contains("Team")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(Team = str_replace_all(Team,c("Win" = "","Loss" = ""))) %>%
  select(-value)
```

Comment: You'd also need `library(tidyr)`

Comment: @apom well spotted, will amend

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

this could be what you are looking for. ( not hardcoded for just 2 teams)

```
# solution 1 :
paste0("Team",ceiling(apply(df[-c(1:3)], 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x)))/2))
[1] "Team1" "Team2" "Team2" "Team1" "Team2"

# solution 2: using a apply() {basically a for loop itself]
apply(df[-c(1:3)], 1, function(x) gsub("(Team\\d)+.*", "\\1", colnames(df[-c(1:3)])[which(!is.na(x))]))
# [1] "Team1" "Team2" "Team2" "Team1" "Team2"

# solution 3: (long route to dplyr) [ you have indirectly taught me a lot in dplyr through my search for this solution]
func <- function(x){
  y = which(x == 1)             # get the location of where 1 appears
  z = rep(0, times = length(x)) # create a vector of 0's+location of 1
  z[y] = y                      # i.e. c(0,0,3,0,5) for Team2Win 
  z
}

df1 = df[-c(1:3)] %>% gather("key", "value", starts_with("Team")) %>% 
                group_by(key) %>%
                dplyr::mutate(x = func(value)) %>%
                filter(x != 0) %>% arrange(x) %>% select(key)

df$newcol = gsub("(Team\\d+).*", "\\1", df1$key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple loop:

```
x = colnames(df)
df$team<- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
 df$team[i] = x[which(df[i,]==1)]
}
```

And then at the end you can trim "win" and "loss" using following function:

```
df$team<- gsub("win", "",df$team)
df$team<- gsub("loss", "",df$team)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you have more than two teams in your data, and team names are not generic. What you want to do is to reshape the data to long form first and extract the relevant team name. So you may want to proceed as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
new_df <- df %>% 
  gather(team,idx,Team1Win:Team100Loss) %>%
  filter(!is.na(idx)) %>%
  select(-idx) %>%
  mutate(team = gsub("Win|Loss","",team))
```

If you want to keep those wide columns, then you can join the new DF to the old one.

Comment: I feel like this is fairly similar to my answer

Comment: Didn't see yours when I put it in. Sorry about that.